# I am facing Auth issue : com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException issue in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, pusher, pusher-js

I am facing issue when I'm connecting pusher with Laravel server.

Error : Pushers: State changed from com.pusher.client.AuthorizationFailureException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://url/auth

Here is my code ->

Gradle :     implementation 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:2.2.5'

```
 fun Pusher(){

    header?.put("Authorization", "Bearer token");

    header?.put("Accept", "application/json");
    header?.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    val authorizer = HttpAuthorizer("http://url/chat/auth")

    authorizer.setHeaders(header)

    val options = PusherOptions()
     options.setCluster("key_cluster");
    options.setHost("url.com")
    options.setWssPort(6001)
    options.setWsPort(6001)
    options.setEncrypted(true)
    options.authorizer=authorizer
    pusher = Pusher("key", options)

    pusher?.connect(object : ConnectionEventListener {

        override fun onConnectionStateChange(change: ConnectionStateChange) {
            if (change.getCurrentState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                subscribeToChannel();
            }
            Log.i("Pusher", "State changed from ${change.previousState} to ${change.currentState}")
        }

        override fun onError(
                message: String?,
                code: String?,
                e: Exception?
        ) {
               }
    }, ConnectionState.ALL)
 }

    fun subscribeToChannel() {
    channel = pusher!!.subscribePrivate("private-conect", object : PrivateChannelEventListener {
     
        override fun onEvent(event: PusherEvent?) {

        }

        override fun onAuthenticationFailure(s: String, e: java.lang.Exception) {
            
        }
    })
}
```